# Method cannot access class variable of different class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing an algorithm in Python that is supposed to sort children (out of a database table) into one of their chosen kindergarten wishes (also out of a database table) following certain criteria on who to guarantee a place in their chosen kindergarten first. For this I first wrote a `KitaDAO` class to link the programme to the database and fetch information out of certain tables, saving them as an object.

```
import pymysql
import json
from Kita import Kita
from Kind import Kind
from Element import Element

class KitaDAO():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = pymysql.connect("localhost","projekt","projekt","kita" )
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.kitaList = []
        self.kinderList = []


def getKitas(self):
    self.sql = "SELECT * FROM kitas"
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(self.sql)
        self.results = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for row in self.results:
            thisKita = Kita(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8])
            self.kitaList.append(thisKita)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
    return self.kitaList

def getWarteliste(self):
    self.sql = "SELECT * FROM warteliste"
    self.warteliste = []
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(self.sql)
        self.results = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for row in self.results:
            thisElement = Element(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6])
            self.warteliste.append(thisElement)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
    return self.warteliste


def getKinder(self):
    self.sql = "SELECT * FROM kinderprofil"
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(self.sql)
        self.results = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for row in self.results:
            thisKind = Kind(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6])
            self.kinderList.append(thisKind)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
    return self.kinderList

def getKindOnWarteliste(self,kita,wunschnummer):
    self.kinderList = []
    self.warteliste = []
    self.warteliste = self.getWarteliste()

    if (wunschnummer == 1):
        for i in self.warteliste:
            if (kita == i.getWunsch1()):
                self.kinderList.append(i.getKind())
    elif (wunschnummer == 2):
        for i in self.warteliste:
            if (kita == i.getWunsch2()):
                self.kinderList.append(i.getKind())
    elif (wunschnummer == 3):
        for i in self.warteliste:
            if (kita == i.getWunsch3()):
                self.kinderList.append(i.getKind())
    else:
        print("Error: Eine ungültige Wunschnummer wurde übergeben.")

    return self.kinderList
```

If needed I can also post the classes `Element`, `Kind` and `Kita` in here but they basically only contain an `__init__` method and if needed a `get` method. They also work, I have tested that before.

My problem is now, that in my main class called `Sortierung` I made `thisDAO` an instance of `KitaDAO` and want to use it to call methods and such, as normally. Sadly the class variable `thisDAO` is not accessible in a method of `Sortierung`. So basically this code has the response:

```
File "Sortierung.py", line 3, in <module> class Sortierung():
File "Sortierung.py", line 30, in Sortierung checkBetreuung(i,warteliste)
File "Sortierung.py", line 11, in checkBetreuung KinderObjektListe = thisDAO.getKinder()
nameError: name 'thisDAO' is not defined
```

I marked the lines in the code under here.

```
from KitaDAO import KitaDAO

class Sortierung(): #---------- This is line 3
    kitas = []
    thisDAO = KitaDAO()
    kitas = thisDAO.getKitas()

def checkBetreuung(kita,kinderIDListe):
    KinderObjektListe = []
    KinderObjektListe = thisDAO.getKinder() #---------This is line 11

#left something out here that was irrelevant


for x in range(1,4):
    for i in kitas:
        warteliste = []
        warteliste = thisDAO.getKindOnWarteliste(i.getID,x)
        checkBetreuung(i,warteliste) #-------------This is line 30
```

Also BTW I am German that is why the variable names are all in German. Sorry :)

Comment: Have you created `Sortierung` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `Sortierung` class at all (this is not Java; not everything needs to be encapsulated in a class) – the root problem is `thisDAO` ends up being a class attribute of it.

Something like

```py
from KitaDAO import KitaDAO

thisDAO = KitaDAO()
kitas = thisDAO.getKitas()

def checkBetreuung(kita, kinderIDListe):
    KinderObjektListe = thisDAO.getKinder()

for x in range(1,4):
    for i in kitas:
        warteliste = thisDAO.getKindOnWarteliste(i.getID(), x)
        checkBetreuung(i, warteliste)
```

should do the trick, barring any other problems.

Comment: While better, this is still incredibly convoluted Python code, and `checkBetreuung` doesn’t do anything useful.

Comment: Hence "barring any other problems". I assume OP has just elided doing whatever with them.

Comment: Thank you I am gonna try it out. You got me, I was doing a lot of java before this haha. Btw checkBetreuung is doing more, I just figured it is irrelevant to make this Question any longer by showing it. It was not the problem and it works.

Comment: So it actually worked, that was easy. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, glad to help!